# convert boolean value into MutableLiveData<Boolean>

Tags: kotlin, data-structures, viewmodel, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

```
var booleanresult : MutableLiveData<Boolean>? = null

fun checksubcat() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val trueorfalse : Boolean = productsDao.getSubCatId(subcat_id)
    booleanresult?.value = trueorfalse
    Log.e("update","view model"+booleanresult?.value.toString())
}
```

Log value for trueorfalse variable :

2022-09-18 06:58:32.305 11820-11849/com.store.pasumainew E/update: **trueorfalse : false**

I got log value of null for booleanresult:

2022-09-18 06:58:32.305 11820-11849/com.store.pasumainew E/update: **booleanresult : null**

I need booleanresult as MutableLiveData ..how to set trueorfalse value to MutableLiveData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LiveData property should not be nullable and should never be null. And it should not even be a `var` because there should never be a reason to create a new one instead of setting the value of the existing instance.

Declare it as non-nullable (no question mark), give it an initial value, and make it a `val`.

```
val booleanResult = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
```

You also can’t directly set the value using Dispatchers.IO. Convention is to usually not change the dispatcher for your launch call but only use it for specific sections of your coroutine using `withContext`. But if for some reason you didn’t follow the convention, then you need to use `postValue()` instead of `value =`, since that is only allowed to be done on the main thread.

Comment: thank you , will you please share the code @Tenfour04

Comment: You mean about the last paragraph? You just need to delete `(Dispatchers.IO)`. If you were calling an actual blocking function , you would put `withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ }` around it. If you define your DAO functions as `suspend` functions, they aren’t blocking so you won’t need that.